# How to load UI forms in QT?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

In my project i have 2 ui files (mainwindow.ui,myform.ui),2 source files(main.cpp,mainwindow.cpp) and 1 header file(mainwindow.h).mainwindow and myform are simple windows.mainwindow having a button. i need to show the myform window when clicking the button in mywindow.HOW?

Comment: Questions posted here should be more specific. http://stackoverflow.com/faq I suggest you spend some time reading the Qt documentation. Perhaps starting here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstarted-develop.html. Then, if you still can't get your project working, come back and ask for help.

Comment: can you please suggest any help for above scenario.i have already take a look at the above url

Comment: You need to connect your button's clicked() signal to a slot on your mainwindow. If you don't know how to do that, try reading this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: i know the signal slot working and i already show another window using a button click.but that window contain a ui file and a cpp class file.But the present scenario is,i need to show a window that have only a ui form file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot load UI forms in QT.you can make a widget class an load that class instead of loading ui files